# EF ChangeTracker Accessing Tracked Entity and its navigation collection

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I would like to track changes. I have a class/model

```
public class Emp
{ 
    public MoreInfo MoreInfo { get; set; }  
    public ICollection<Works> Works { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


foreach (var e in _db.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>())
{
   foreach (var key in e.Properties)
   {  
         if (key.IsModified)
         {
          //I can get the FirstName, LastName fields
         }
   }
}
```

But I cant figure out how do I loop MoreInfo  and ICollection Works and check its parameters  ?

Answer (score 4):

By EF Core terminology these are not properties, but *navigations*, so they cannot be accessed through `Properties`. Use [`Navigations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.navigations?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_Navigations) property to get entries (with common properties/methods) for both reference and collection navigation properties

```
foreach (var navEntry in e.Navigations)
{
    // e.MoreInfo, e.Works
    if (navEntry.IsModified)
    {
    }
}
```

or [`Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.references?view=efcore-5.0) and [`Collections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.collections?view=efcore-5.0) to get the respective entries (with specific properties/methods)

```
foreach (var refEntry in e.References)
{
    // e.MoreInfo
    if (refEntry.IsModified)
    {
    }
}
foreach (var colEntry in e.Collections)
{
    // e.Works
    if (colEntry.IsModified)
    {
    }
}
```

But both *properties* and *navigations* are considered to be *members*, so you can use [`Members`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.members?view=efcore-5.0) to process them all using the common properties/methods

```
foreach (var memberEntry in e.Members)
{
    // e.MoreInfo, e.Works, e.FirstName, e.LastName
    if (memberEntry.IsModified)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have tired to use the foreach(... e.References) when checking IsModified > it is set to always false. My model MoreInfo has a field Address and I see in the debug refEntry> CurrentValue> Address containing new value. Where would I see the original value Address  ?  With e.Properties I see key.OriginalValue and key.CurrentValue, Is there something similar to see original and current value?

Comment: `IsModified` has different meaning for different member types, which is explained in the corresponding class documentation. For references, you should look at [ReferenceEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.referenceentry?view=efcore-5.0) class. For instance, [TargetEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.referenceentry.targetentry?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_ReferenceEntry_TargetEntry) gives you access to the related entity data.

Comment: From there you could access its properties, references, collections similar to the way you do with the "main" entry. But all that's a different story (and question).

Comment: Ok to access the properties it is a different story as you mentioned but what about the IsModified, it is always showing false, any ideas how to get the correct result when field is modified in the reference entry and in the collection ? Can you help with example I can test, with your example it is always showing false? Thanks