# EF Core: ChangeTracker and navigation collection of related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have trouble understanding how to get useful information from ChangeTracker in EF core when it comes to Navigation properties / many-to-many relations.
Essentially, I want to know when a relation between two entities was changed, e.g a relation was added or removed.

Here are my simplified entity classes and their join entity/table:

```
public class Singer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<SingerChoir> SingerChoirs {get; set;}
}

public class Choir
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
 
    public ICollection<SingerChoir> ChoirSingers {get; set;}
}

public class SingerChoir
{
    public int SingerId {get;set;}
    public int ChoirId {get;set;}
    public Singer Singer {get;set;}
    public Choir Choir {get;set;}
}
```

Using the DebugView of ChangeTracker is can see that the information is available correctly, but I cannot figure out how to access the information that an entry in the join-table was deleted for example:

```
DebugView: 
Singer {Id: 1} Unchanged
Id: 1 PK
Name: 'MyTest'
SingerChoirs: [{SingerId: 1, ChoirId: 1}, {SingerId: 1, ChoirId: 4}]
SingerChoir {SingerId: 1, ChoirId: 1} Unchanged
  SingerId: 1 PK FK
  ChoirId: 1 PK FK
  Choir: <null>
  Singer: {Id: 1}
SingerChoir {SingerId: 1, ChoirId: 3} Added
  SingerId: 1 PK FK
  ChoirId: 3 PK FK
  Choir: <null>
  Singer: {Id: 1}
```

I am able to filter for modified navigations but I don't see a way to get detailed information from that point onward.
I found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67540664/ef-changetracker-accessing-tracked-entity-and-its-navigation-collection) but the mentioned [`ReferenceEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.referenceentry?view=efcore-5.0) class is unavailable for Navigations and [`NavigationEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.navigationentry?view=efcore-6.0) does not have any TargetEntry property. What's a good approach to get more information about the relational changes?

Thank you for any hints!

```
ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
foreach (var e in ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>())
{
    foreach (var n in e.Navigations.Where(n => n.IsModified))
    {
        // this is where I am lost ->
        // how do I get access to the modified SingerChoir entity and its own EntityState and Properties?
       // ideally something like:
       n.TargetEntry.Properties.OriginalValues 
       n.TargetEntry.Properties.CurrentValues

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just noticied that the Singer entity remains `'Unchanged'` rather than `'Modified'` as it was in the DebugView of the original post version. This was due to a bug that also altered a base property of Singer. I changed the DebugView output.

Comment: where do you execute all the code `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();...`? is this in a method? or just in any business-logic code?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Since my goal is to automatically populare an audit log - I thought that within the DbContext's ```SaveChangesAsync``` method was a good idea. That's were it is today. Alternatively an [interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#savechanges-interception) could also be a good solution.

Comment: ah okay, it's not obvious where you put it ;) I did something similar and imho, savechangesasync is the right place

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for now:

As per the last update:
The ChangeTracker did not flag the main entity `'Singer'` as `'Modified'` so my approach of trying to get information via the main entities `'NavigationEntry'` or `'CollectionEntry'` wasn't going to work as the ChangeTracker wouldn't hand the main entity to me (as it wasn't changed, only the relations).

However, since I am using explicit entities to represent the relationship (`SingerChoir`) I can make the ChangeTracker hand me those explicitly by using e.g. an (empty) interface:

```
public class SingerChoir : IRelationalEntity
{
    public int SingerId {get;set;}
    public int ChoirId {get;set;}
    public Singer Singer {get;set;}
    public Choir Choir {get;set;}
}
```

That way I can explicitly handle those relational changes:

```
ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
foreach (var e in ChangeTracker.Entries<IRelationalEntity>()
.Where(e => e.State is EntityState.Added or EntityState.Deleted))
{
    var trail = new AuditTrail(e); //access .State, .CurrentValues, etc   

}
```

Maybe there are more elegant ways - for now I can do everything I needed with this approach.

This will probably not work when the join-entity/join class is mapped by [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions)